# MySQL query Optimization for limit offset query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this particular query:

```
SELECT users.role, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email,
   projects.project_id, projects.reminder, projects.title, projects.user_id,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=0 THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_citations,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=1 THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_citations_deleted,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=0 AND authors.first_name != "" AND authors.last_name !="" AND authors.last_name NOT LIKE "author_lastname%" AND authors.last_name NOT LIKE "author_firstname%" THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_citations_filled,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=0 AND citations.user_comment IS NOT NULL THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_comments,
   (CASE WHEN user_stats.type IN (4,66,67,68,73,74) THEN user_stats.type ELSE NULL END) AS source,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_stats.type=1 THEN user_stats.id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_export_word,
   MAX(CASE WHEN user_stats.type=1 THEN user_stats.timestamp ELSE NULL END) AS last_export_word,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_stats.type=3 THEN user_stats.id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_export_email,
   MAX(CASE WHEN user_stats.type=3 THEN user_stats.timestamp ELSE NULL END) AS last_export_email,
   MAX(export_format_class_name) as exported_style
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN projects_styles ON projects_styles.project_id = projects.project_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = projects.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_stats ON user_stats.project_id = projects.project_id
LEFT JOIN citations ON citations.project_id = projects.project_id
LEFT JOIN citations_authors ON citations_authors.citation_id = citations.citation_id
LEFT JOIN authors ON authors.author_id = citations_authors.author_id
GROUP BY projects.project_id
ORDER BY projects.project_id DESC
LIMIT 0,4000;
```

For low offset is working fine, but for 12000 or 16000 offset it works very bad. I know that this is normal but the time raise exponential for each offset, and I think this is not normal thing. I guess that my query is not so optimal that I thought.

Later Edit: 
This is the explanation of my query:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
"1","SIMPLE","projects","index",NaN,"PRIMARY","4",NaN,"102","55850.00",""
"1","SIMPLE","projects_styles","ref","projects_styles_project_id_index","projects_styles_project_id_index","4","citelighter.projects.project_id","1","100.00",""
"1","SIMPLE","users","eq_ref","PRIMARY","PRIMARY","4","citelighter.projects.user_id","1","100.00",""
"1","SIMPLE","user_stats","ref","user_stats_project_id_index","user_stats_project_id_index","5","citelighter.projects.project_id","13","100.00",""
"1","SIMPLE","citations","ref","citations_project_id_index","citations_project_id_index","4","citelighter.projects.project_id","3","100.00",""
"1","SIMPLE","citations_authors","ref","citations_authors_citation_id_index","citations_authors_citation_id_index","4","citelighter.citations.citation_id","1","100.00",""
"1","SIMPLE","authors","eq_ref","PRIMARY","PRIMARY","4","citelighter.citations_authors.author_id","1","100.00",""
```

Comment: why do you want a 10000 offset?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the execution path of the query to see why it might be running so slowly when there is a 10000 offset?

Comment: At a glance, I don't see anything that would make the duration grow exponentially. Looks rather linear to me (though rather steep). While MySQL may choose different execution paths based on certain counts, I doubt the cut off is between 4 and 10 thousand. Compare the `EXPLAIN` result to be sure.

Comment: Arg! I know this doesn't answer your specific question but your `GROUP BY` is wrong. I know MySQL lets you use `GROUP BY` this way but it is illogical and wrong. All columns that are not being aggregated should be included in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have to export all data from there in a csv file. The execution time is like:
Offset 0 - 26 sec 
Offset 4000 - 1 min 33 sec
Offset 8000 - 3 min 41 sec
Offset 12000 - 7 min 20 sec
Offset 16000 - 13 min 05 sec
Offset 20000 - 19 min 22 sec

Comment: @Zane, Why do you think that the GROUP BY is wrong placed in this query. Please be more explicitly.

Comment: @Urmelinho not sure how much more specific I could be. If you're writing an a statement with any aggregation. All columns that aren't being aggregated must be in the `Group By` for the statement to be correct.

Comment: @Zane, you are telling me that I should remove project_id from GROUP BY and add all other columns that are under SELECT statement (users.role, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email,projects.reminder, projects.title) ? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No I'm saying add those as well as project_id anything that doesn't have some sort of aggregate function on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can look at the execution plan of the query.  Just prepend the query with the `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` keywords.  It's a great way to see if the query is hitting the indexes you think it's hitting, or if it's having to do full table scans, etc.  For an example of the output, see the MySQL docs for [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html).  This will be the first step you'll want to take in optimizing the query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT users.role, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email,
    projects.project_id, projects.reminder, projects.title, projects.user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=0 THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_citations,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=1 THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_citations_deleted,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=0 AND authors.first_name != "" AND authors.last_name !="" AND authors.last_name NOT LIKE "author_lastname%" AND authors.last_name NOT LIKE "author_firstname%" THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_citations_filled,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN citations.deleted=0 AND citations.user_comment IS NOT NULL THEN citations.citation_id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_comments,
    (CASE WHEN user_stats.type IN (4,66,67,68,73,74) THEN user_stats.type ELSE NULL END) AS source,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_stats.type=1 THEN user_stats.id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_export_word,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_stats.type=1 THEN user_stats.timestamp ELSE NULL END) AS last_export_word,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN user_stats.type=3 THEN user_stats.id ELSE NULL END) AS nr_export_email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_stats.type=3 THEN user_stats.timestamp ELSE NULL END) AS last_export_email,
    MAX(export_format_class_name) as exported_style
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN projects_styles ON projects_styles.project_id = projects.project_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = projects.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_stats ON user_stats.project_id = projects.project_id
LEFT JOIN citations ON citations.project_id = projects.project_id
LEFT JOIN citations_authors ON citations_authors.citation_id = citations.citation_id
LEFT JOIN authors ON authors.author_id = citations_authors.author_id
GROUP BY projects.project_id
ORDER BY projects.project_id DESC
LIMIT 0,4000;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because it needs to evaluate all those offset rows,before returning the desired rows.
What you could try is to add a WHERE condition on a unqiue key,but this assumes no gaps in the key,which is unlikely.But for export to csv,just create a new unique column and use that.

```
WHERE  unique_col > 10000 ORDER BY unique_col LIMIT 4000;
```

Comment: So I should make pagination with where clause ?

Comment: No for pagination this wont work,because people will skip pages,so you cant know that offset before.You could calculate it on click but the question is who uses pagination with thousand of rows?(which is your problem)

Comment: I suppose to get all data from table to put in a CSV. So I'm doing this by getting from database 4000 rows per step.